# How could Nagini seem to see Harry and Hermione through the invisibility cloak when they visited Godric's Hollow in Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Nagini seemed to be able to see Harry and Hermione though Harry's invisibility cloak while they were visiting Harry's old house in Godric's Hollow.

> Harry had the strangest feeling that she knew that they were there, and also who they were. Just as he reached this uneasy conclusion, she raised a gloved hand and beckoned.
>   *- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

Could the snake actually see them, or was it all based off of the assumption that someone was in front of the Potter's house and that it could be Harry?

Comment: Also, the Horcrux

Comment: Why would you think Nagini "saw" them? Snakes have an excellent sense of smell.

Comment: The Horcrux comment is a good point. The book does describe the locket as reacting to Nagini's presence. So maybe it works the other way around as well.

Comment: May be related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7467/could-cats-see-through-the-invisibility-cloak

Comment: @GorchestopherH I'm pretty sure it never mentioned this, but for some reason I always interpreted it such that, since Harry's invisibility cloak was Death's, which made the wearer *truly* invisible, it also masked sounds and smells. Thinking about it though, I guess it probably wouldn't mask voices or smells.

Comment: @TylerH I'm fairly sure truly invisibility just means you're truly not "visible".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

TL:DR - last line.

The Fandom article [Cloak of Invisibility](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Cloak_of_Invisibility) (under Behind the Scenes) provides some relevant information. It may be unreliable, but let me elaborate.

Many things could detect people who were using the Cloak, as we see in the series, such as the eye that Moody possesses and the Marauder's Map. Now, the last bit sounds interesting.

> It was also unable to hide Harry from creatures able to sense location by methods other than primarily sight, such as Dementors and Nagini.

Animals that use senses to roam **could** be able to see under the Cloak (possibly echo location, and snakes).

Dementors can as well, which may lead to snakes being able to.

> "Dementors can’t see, you know. . . .” He swallowed. “They feel their way toward people by feeding off their emotions" — Sirius

Emotions such as fear can be sensed by Dementors — if you possess fear, they may be able to know where you are due to this, Cloak or not. As it only protects the user from some spells and sight, I'd assume the latter is correct.

Although different, Mrs. Norris and Crookshanks may have sensed the presence under the the Cloak as well.

**As Dementors can sense people under Cloaks via fear, it reinforces the statement that snakes can sense anyone under the Cloak via smell, and possibly heat.**

Comment: Interesting.. I'm surprised a "make-me-able-to-smell-things-incredibly-well" spell was never used in the (many) instances where people suspected nearby invisible persons, or even to track people (*visible or not*) like a hound might.

Comment: What do you mean by "detect the Cloak" or "sense Cloaks"? This makes no sense. Now, being able to detect what's inside of the cloak, despite the cloak's abilities makes perfect sense.

Comment: What spells does the Cloak protect against?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The cloak itself is protected against the summoning charm (one of the Death Eaters tries to "Accio Cloak" when they go to Hogsmede in Deathly Hallows but it doesn't work). I don't know if there's any mention of the cloak protecting the user from spells though.

Comment: @CrowTRobot Ah yes, good point!

Comment: @Ellesedil By "sense the cloak" I merely mean it and anything under it.

Comment: @CrowTRobot It doesn't protect the user from spells, as seen in Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince. Harry was wearing it to spy on Malfoy on the Hogworts Express, but Malfoy was able to use a paralyzing hex on Harry while he was under the cloak.

Comment: @JoeJMCIT Some spells do not - such as Homenum Revelio, and Petrificus Totalus.

Comment: Snakes also have a keen sense of vibrations, and may have sensed Harry that way.

Comment: Don't know about echo-location, but snakes do have a keen sense of smell - or rather "tasting" the air.  And as they move on the ground, they may pick up vibrations of people moving.  Finally some snakes can "see" the heat coming off prey with special receptors.

Comment: I don't think it's heat - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116671/36769

Comment: I thought the invisibility cloak was supposed to be able to hide you from Death.  Is Death really such a chump that his detection methods are worse than Moody's magic eye?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is totally wrong. Nagini is not a Dementor. We have literally 0 reason to presume that she (or Mrs Norris or anyone else) could sense emotions like a Dementor.

Answer (score 29):

Snakes don't see very well, they sense (and hunt and navigate) almost entirely through heat and smell.

According to Harry Potter Fandom article on [Nagini](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Nagini), Nagini may be a fictional variety of venomous python. Just like pit vipers, pythons have heat receptors.

Rowling has at least [partially confirmed](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript) this theory:

> **Jess:** How did nagini could see harry and hermione if they were under the invisibility cloak?
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** Snakes’ sense are very different from human ones. They can detect heat and movement in a way that we can’t.

Comment: i think your correct and your statements a good answer, however, I'd perhaps link to something confirming this ability of snakes to verify.

Comment: Cobras don't have pits to sense heat.

Comment: Rowling has at least [partially confirmed](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript) your theory: "**Jess:** How did nagini could see harry and hermione if they were under the invisibility cloak
**J.K. Rowling:** Snakes’ sense are very different from human ones. They can detect heat and movement in a way that we can’t." Might be worth adding in

Comment: @DoubleDouble And Nagini isn't a viper. She has a hood.

Comment: Ah right, sorry - thrown off by the movie depiction.

Comment: @Axelrod according to the sources I cited she's a python which has pits.

Comment: [Related to Nagini's species](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14541/32946)

Comment: @DoubleDouble Harry Potter wikia says Python, and jk Rowling says heat, so I think the discussion is over.

Comment: The source you linked reasoned that she must be a viper because she might sense heat. The quote you posted merely shows that Herpetology is another of Rowling's weak points. Logically, Nagini would need to be a viper to sense heat but she would have to be a cobra or false cobra to have a hood.

Comment: @DoubleDouble And the king cobra grows to 18 feet, not rarely up to 6. Man, why can't people just Google?

Comment: Personally, I think the quote is vague enough not to assume heat pits. "*They can detect heat and movement in a way that we can’t*" is referring to generic snake senses, which she probably thought all snakes had. But even cobras use their tongue to taste/smell their surroundings, so the quote is still somewhat accurate. Regardless, the only similarity in the book's description to a python is Nagini's thickness.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the question wasn't about species it was about how nagini could detect and track Harry under the cloak. The conversation is a rabbit hole.

Comment: As I said elsewhere, I believe heat detection wouldn't work - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116671/36769.

Comment: It still doesn't matter, JK Rowling is the source of all truth and knowledge related to the potterverse, and that's her explanation.

Answer (score 11):

Nagini is some variety of cobra — she has a hood — but I believe the author mistakenly conflated her abilities with that of a pit viper.

Pit vipers have [heat sensing organs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_sensing_in_snakes#) in their heads (see the picture below) which give them basic infrared sensing.

[image: two snakes, with arrows pointing to the pit organs around their mouths]

Cobras, however, do not have heat sensing organs and, combined with their relatively poor senses (aside from sight, which is fairly good), it would make no sense for a cobra to be able to sense an invisible person.

That said, this is a series about *wizards* and heavily features *magic*. The cloak only prevents sight, the snake is an unrealistic green color for a cobra — either JK Rowling made a mistake (likely) or [a wizard did it](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AWizardDidIt).

Comment: Keeping in mind that "fairly good" means "can accurately spit in your eye from 4 to 8 feet away -- not exactly extraordinary.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  It's true snakes have a poor sense of sight and hearing in general, but their sense of smell is quite good, and due to their forked tongues, they can smell directionally, much the way we hear.  They also possess the ability to feel vibrations.  Both of these senses should allow Nagini to detect Harry without sight.

Comment: @Kai You have a point. Repost it on the answers that matter!

Comment: Heat detection seems unlikely - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116671/36769

Answer (score 10):

This is speculative, but considering that Harry could feel the presence of other Horcruxes nearby (being one of Voldemort's horcruxes himself), and Nagini was a Horcrux, it's very possible that she could sense his presence.

As with Harry, even though he could sense other nearby Horcruxes, he did not immediately recognize that it was because he himself was one. Similarly Nagini may have sensed the presence of *something* there, but not known exactly what it was.

Considering that the snake was there to essentially keep an eye on Godric's Hollow, it would have been wary of anything suspicious, including an odd sense of something there, so would have at least investigated it. It just so happened to be the very person she was waiting for.

In addition, Harry and Hermione were in possession of the locket Horcrux at this point as well, therefore their presence would have been twice as potent to the snake. This may be why it could sense them long before they realized it was there.

Answer (score 4):

The cloak, as the Deathly Hallow, is completely invisible as Mr. Lovegood explains in the Deathly Hallows on page 354. We can presume the snake couldn't see him or smell him or anything alike.

> "I mean to say, it is not a traveling cloak imbued with a Disillusionment Charm, or carrying a Bedazzling Hex or else woven from Demiguise hair, which will hide one initially but fade with the years until it turns opaque. We are talking about a cloak that really and truly renders the wearer completely invisible, and endures eternally, giving constant and impenetrable concealment, no matter what spells are cast at it..."

Even if Nagini could somehow, Harry looked and smelled like another man since he was under the influence of the Polyjuice potion. However, the Horcruxes can feel the presence of one another as they are essentially parts of the same soul and I think that is how Nagini knew Harry was there, even though, later on, it had to confirm before calling Lord Voldemort.

Answer (score 1):

Magic dammit!  Or maybe smell or movement sensing.

Most of the other answers* here involve a snake's ability to detect heat. The trouble I have with this is that snakes detect heat at a distance by ["seeing" in the infrared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_sensing_in_snakes). Since infrared - like visible light - is a sub-continuum of the electromagnetic spectrum, I'm inclined to think an invisibility cloak would block infrared radiation in addition to visible light, so I think it is NOT Nagini's ability to sense heat.

As others mention, snakes have excellent senses of smell, so Nagini might have used that to detect Harry and Hermione. Snakes also feel vibrations that would give away their movements. Of course, it's possible that some magical ability (horcrux detecting another horcrux, enchantment to counter invisibility, etc.) allowed her to find them.

*Some even citing Rowling, which tells me she probably hasn't done a good job researching this and thinking it through.

Comment: It is totally possible that the Cloak cloaks the visible portion of the electromagnetic spectrum.

Comment: @Krumia: Yes, I suppose it's possible, but would not really be sensible, IMO. After all, with non-magical equipment even us muggles can see in the infrared, so an invisibility cloak could easily be rendered ineffective.

Comment: Ah! But people like Arthur Weasley is fascinated by the stuff **muggles use in place of magic**. Probably Peverell brothers wouldn't have anticipated infrared cameras from muggles. Also [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116549/29074). Heat *is* actually infrared.

Answer (score 1):

One more **physics** angle:
Humans emit a hot-body radiation of infrared at 37 °C and snakes are able to recognize them at a one-meter distance.

Assuming now the Invisibility Cloak only blocks visible light, then the cloak is susceptible to the infrared radiation. So snakes can sense them. Even Filch's cat, Mrs. Norris, does in the first part.

Now, given the design of the Cloak, it was said that Death gave the brother this cloak so that no one can find him. That should mean that cloak should not be sensed by any creature. Kind of a paradox to me.

So the Horcrux explanation stands well!

Comment: Well, the cloak may not *actually* have been made by Death. Dumbledore puts forth this explanation later in the book. Also, Moody’s eye could see through the cloak (possibly because it saw in a different part of the spectrum, as well).

Comment: Also, some of the other answers suggest that not all snakes can detect heat. But then again, Nagini is certainly no ordinary snake!

Answer (score 0):

Harry Potter himself was the 7th and the last unwanted Horcrux that Voldemort accidentally created while trying to kill him in Godric's Hollow on the night Harry's parents died.

All Voldemort's Horcruxes had a connection (allowing Harry to sense the cup in Gringotts Bank and see and find Voldemort in Deathly Hallows).

Also, as Dumbledore said in the Half-Blood Prince, dark magic like that of Horcruxes has traces. I believe that's why Nagini could sense the presence of Harry even beneath the invisibility cloak.